# How to check if a string contains an element from an array in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to check if string $name ends with any of the elements from $end array_ref

```
my $end=['.a[bc', '.de[f', '.xy]z'];
my $name="test.a[bc";

# But this is not working:
if(grep{$name=~m/\Q.+$_$/} @{$end}) { print "Yes\n"; } else {print "No\n"; } # prints "No"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\Q` escapes (and thus matches literally) `.+` and `$` (in addition to the contents of `$_`).

Fix:

```
grep { $name =~ /\Q$_\E\z/ } @{$end}
```

- You don't need the `.+` part at all.
- `\E` limits the escaping to just `$_`.
- `\z` anchors the match to the end of the string (`$` would also allow a `\n` before the end of the string).

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to offer an alternative solution without using regex. Since the problem is is to compare a string with a sub-string, `substr()` function can be used:

```
my $end = ['.a[bc', '.de[f', '.xy]z'];
my $name= "test.a[bc" ;
my $found = grep { (substr($name, length($name) - length($_)) eq $_) } @$end;
print $found ? "Yes\n": "No\n";
```

This is assuming `length($name) >= length($_)`. In fact, the behaviour of `substr` can also allow us to simply pass a negative offset (2nd parameter):

```
my $found = grep { (substr($name, -length($_)) eq $_) } @$end;
```

One thing to note here is that `substr()` generally produce no errors and warnings and still do something -- since it takes both positive and negative offset values. (Check [perldoc of substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#substr-EXPR%2cOFFSET%2cLENGTH%2cREPLACEMENT) (command: `perldoc -f substr`) for more details).

You can avoid those "surprises" by adding a pre-condiditon to guard this seemingly trivial assumption:

```
my $found = grep {
    (length($name) > length($_)) &&
    (substr($name, -length($_)) eq $_)
} @$end;
```

This does makes sense: if the content in `$_` is longer than `$name`, by definition it cannot be the suffix of `$name` anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this non-regex solution. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `grep()` , you need to convert the `$end` variable to an array by using `split()`. Note that `grep(/pattern/,@array)` searches for `/pattern/` in each element of `@array`. Since you are searching for last four characters in your pattern , we need to separate it first.

```
my $end="'.a[bc', '.de[f', '.xy]z'";
my @array = split(',',$end);
my $name="test.a[bc";
my $name_end = substr($name,-5);

if( grep( m/\Q$name_end/ , @array ) ) {
    print "Yes\n";
}
else {
    print "No\n";
} # prints "No";
```

An alternative would be to to search in the `$end` for each array element by looping. The above solution works however. Let me know your feedback.

Comment: `$end` is not a string. It's an array reference.

Comment: Thanks!. I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $end=['.a[bc', '.de[f', '.xy]z'];
my $name="test.a[bc";
my %end;
@end{@$end}=();
my $found = exists $end{($name=~/.*(\..*)/)[0]};
```